# buildozer error: there was a problem for ssl certificate

Tags: python, ssl, kivy, buildozer

I am in virtual machine with ubuntu Linux.
So I wanted to build a apk with buildozer and in my requirements I have nothing except kivy and python3. So when I run the buildozer android ebug deploy run command and when it is halfway through it, it showing me always the error .:

This is the error
**Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/cython: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPoolhost = pypi.org . Cant connect to HTTPS URL because the ssl module is not available**

NOTE: The error is showing up when buildozer is trying to install certifi.
So I tried these solutions:
-- Gone trough some answers in stackoverflow
-- installed libssl-dev, because it was a ssl error
-- installed all need packages for pip and my virtual machine

But none of them helped me. I don't even have certifi in my requirements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I finally figured it out. For anyone who has same problem in Linux. Do sudo apt install libssl-dev. Then do buildozer Android clean and delete your .buildozer file. Then do buildozer Android debug only not buildozer Android debug deploy run. You can do it later.

This solved the issue for me

Comment: In my case on CentOS 7 the "buildozer android debug deploy run" also worked fine directly post installing yum install openssl-devel and buildozer clean. Even haven't removed .buildozer too