# buidozer is showing an error while i try to debug an kivy app

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I am trying to develop an kivy android application,but while debugging the app using 'buildozer android debug deploy run' command the buildozer throws the following error i confirmed that cython is installed in my system

```
    [INFO]:    # Installing pure Python modules
    [INFO]:    *** PYTHON PACKAGE / PROJECT INSTALL STAGE ***
    [INFO]:    The requirements (certifi) don't have recipes, attempting to install them with pip
    [INFO]:    If this fails, it may mean that the module has compiled components and needs a recipe.
    [INFO]:    -> directory context /home/mohanraj/Desktop/mohan/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build
    [INFO]:    -> running python3 -m venv venv
    [INFO]:    Upgrade pip to latest version
    [INFO]:    -> running bash -c source venv/bin/activate && pip install -U pip
    [INFO]:    Install Cython in case one of the modules needs it to build                                                         
    [INFO]:    -> running bash -c venv/bin/pip install Cython
            working: Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl ...(and 207 more) Exception in thread background thread for pid 5232:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    File "/home/mohanraj/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 1662, in wrap
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/mohanraj/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 2606, in background_thread
        handle_exit_code(exit_code)
    File "/home/mohanraj/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 2304, in fn
        return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
    File "/home/mohanraj/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 877, in handle_command_exit_code
        raise exc
    sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

    RAN: /usr/bin/bash -c 'venv/bin/pip install Cython'

    STDOUT:
    WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
    Collecting Cython
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
    Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/cython/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/cython/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
    ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Cython (from versions: none)
    ERROR: No matching distribution found for Cython
    WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
    Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping


    STDERR:

    Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                             
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
        return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
        exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/home/mohanraj/Desktop/mohan/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1231, in <module>
        main()
    File "/home/mohanraj/Desktop/mohan/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
        ToolchainCL()
    File "/home/mohanraj/Desktop/mohan/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 688, in __init__
        getattr(self, command)(args)
    File "/home/mohanraj/Desktop/mohan/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 154, in wrapper_func
        build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
    File "/home/mohanraj/Desktop/mohan/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 205, in build_dist_from_args
        build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx,
    File "/home/mohanraj/Desktop/mohan/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 596, in build_recipes
        run_pymodules_install(
    File "/home/mohanraj/Desktop/mohan/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 776, in run_pymodules_install
        shprint(sh.bash, '-c', (
    File "/home/mohanraj/Desktop/mohan/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 167, in shprint
        for line in output:
    File "/home/mohanraj/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 925, in next
        self.wait()
    File "/home/mohanraj/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 849, in wait
        self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
    File "/home/mohanraj/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 877, in handle_command_exit_code
        raise exc
    sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

    RAN: /usr/bin/bash -c 'venv/bin/pip install Cython'

    STDOUT:
    WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
    Collecting Cython
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
    Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/cython/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/cython/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
    ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Cython (from versions: none)
    ERROR: No matching distribution found for Cython
    WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
    Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping


    STDERR:

    # Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy,openssl --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/mohanraj/Desktop/mohan/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21
    # ENVIRONMENT:
    #     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
    #     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/mohanraj-Lenovo-E41-25:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1637,unix/mohanraj-Lenovo-E41-25:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1637'
    #     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
    #     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
    #     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg'
    #     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'
    #     TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION = '1.45.1'
    #     GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
    #     GTK_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
    #     APPLICATION_INSIGHTS_NO_DIAGNOSTIC_CHANNEL = 'true'
    #     DERBY_HOME = '/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_251/db'
    #     LANGUAGE = 'en_IN:en'
    #     QT4_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
    #     JAVA_HOME = '/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_251'
    #     GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE = 'ubuntu'
    #     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
    #     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
    #     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'ubuntu'
    #     SSH_AGENT_PID = '1554'
    #     BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT = '/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/code_code.desktop'
    #     GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge'
    #     PWD = '/home/mohanraj/Desktop/mohan'
    #     GSETTINGS_SCHEMA_DIR = '/snap/code/33/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas'
    #     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu'
    #     LOGNAME = 'mohanraj'
    #     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
    #     GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
    #     XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
    #     VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_NODE = '/snap/code/33/usr/share/code/code'
    #     J2REDIR = '/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_251/jre'
    #     GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS = 'JS ERROR;JS LOG'
    #     WINDOWPATH = '2'
    #     HOME = '/home/mohanraj'
    #     USERNAME = 'mohanraj'
    #     IM_CONFIG_PHASE = '1'
    #     LANG = 'en_GB.UTF-8'
    #     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
    #     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'Unity'
    #     DISABLE_WAYLAND = '1'
    #     GIT_ASKPASS = '/snap/code/33/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/git/dist/askpass.sh'
    #     INVOCATION_ID = 'ee16fbfeea32418f905fceb027600a71'
    #     MANAGERPID = '1366'
    #     CHROME_DESKTOP = 'code-url-handler.desktop'
    #     CLUTTER_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
    #     GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT = 'stderr'
    #     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
    #     XDG_SESSION_CLASS = 'user'
    #     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
    #     J2SDKDIR = '/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_251'
    #     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
    #     USER = 'mohanraj'
    #     VSCODE_GIT_IPC_HANDLE = '/run/user/1000/snap.code/vscode-git-d79b97ea0e.sock'
    #     DISPLAY = ':0'
    #     SHLVL = '2'
    #     QT_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
    #     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000/snap.code'
    #     VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_MAIN = '/snap/code/33/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/git/dist/askpass-main.js'
    #     JOURNAL_STREAM = '9:39654'
    #     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
    #     PATH = '/home/mohanraj/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/mohanraj/.local/bin:/home/mohanraj/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_251/bin::/snap/bin'
    #     GDMSESSION = 'ubuntu'
    #     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'
    #     GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID = '2184'
    #     GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE = '/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/code_code.desktop'
    #     TERM_PROGRAM = 'vscode'
    #     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
    #     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/mohanraj/.buildozer/android/packages'
    #     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/mohanraj/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
    #     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/mohanraj/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
    #     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
    #     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
    # 
    # Buildozer failed to execute the last command
    # The error might be hidden in the log above this error
    # Please read the full log, and search for it before
    # raising an issue with buildozer itself.
    # In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

I tried reinstalling the cython but it doesn't works.
Is there any other way to debug the kivy application.KivyLauncher is not working since i use kivyMD

Comment: Try installing libssl-dev, or whatever package gives you the ssl dev headers, then clean and build everything again.

Comment: this is a duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61794830/buildozer-error-there-was-a-problem-for-ssl-certificate. It seems like it is bug. But it will be fixed when you follow the solution in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i didnot include the kivymd library in the requirements field in the buildozer.spec,after including all the requirements it worked successfully